# Repopulate form after error validation from another controller Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am really embarrassed with this problem :

I want to post comments from one view and if errors occurs in form, i want the form to be repopulated. I use the render method but my form isn't repopulated.

I specify that the form is displayed from a view and use another controller action, by other words means :

Form called from : views/cars/show.html.erb code below :

```
<h1>Fiche détaillée</h1>

<%= @car.marque %><br>
<%= @car.modele %><br>
<%= @car.nbkm %><br>
<%= @car.couleur %><br>
<%= @car.disponibilite %><br>
<hr>

<% x=0 %>
<h1><%= pluralize(@car.comments.count, 'commentaire') %></h1>
<% @car.comments.each do |k| %>
<%= x+=1 %>
Email : <%= k.email %><br>
Sujet : <%= k.sujet %><br>
Commentaire : <%= k.commentaire %><br>
<%= link_to 'Supprimer', [k.car, k], method: :delete %><br><br>
<% end %>

<hr>

<h1>Ajouter votre commentaire</h1>
<div style='width:300px;'>

<% flash.each do |key, msg| %>
<% if msg.count >0 %>
<p class="bg-danger" style='padding:10px;'><%= pluralize(msg.count,'error') %>
  <ul><% msg.full_messages.each do |m|%>
        <li><%= m %></li>
    <% end %>
</p>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</ul>




<%= form_for([@car,@car.comments.build]) do |co| %>

<%= co.label :'Email' %><br>
<%= co.text_field :email , class: 'form-control' %><br>
<br>
<%= co.label :'Sujet' %><br>
<%= co.text_field :sujet , class: 'form-control'%><br>
<br>
<%= co.label :'Commentaire' %><br>
<%= co.text_area :commentaire , class: 'form-control' %><br>
<br>
<%= co.submit :'Envoyer votre commentaire', class: 'btn btn-info'%>

<% end %>
</div>
```

below my controllers :

Controller 1 : controllers/cars_controller.rb

```
def create
#render text: params[:car].inspect
@car = Car.new(params[:car].permit(:marque,:modele,:nbkm,:couleur,:disponibilite))
  if !@car.save
    render 'new'
  else
    redirect_to @car
  end
end

def show
@car = Car.find(params[:id])
end

def index
@cars=Car.all
end
```

Controller 2 : controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @comment=Comment.new
  end

  def create

    @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
    @comment = @car.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:email,:sujet,:commentaire))

        if !@comment.save


          flash[:error] = @comment.errors
          flash.keep[:error]
          render 'cars/show'

          else
          redirect_to car_path(@car)
        end
  end


  def destroy
    @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
    @comment = @car.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to car_path(@car)
  end

end
```

I really don't understand why it does not work !!

Thank you so much for any assistance ;)

Comment: you code looks very different to rails recommendations. you may try `rails g scaffold name fields ...` so see what i mean?

Comment: sorry but i want to understand whats wrong with my code first to understand how rails works

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

I did some similar tests a bit for your case, the problem should due to the `flash` method.

Replace below lines:

```
flash[:error] = @comment.errors
flash.keep[:error]
render 'cars/show'
```

To:

```
flash.now[:error] = @comment.errors.full_messages
@car.reload
render 'cars/show'
```

Because `flash[:error]` will only be available in next action, means only works in `redirect_to`, so you have to use `flash.now[:error]` for rendering same view template. And most importantly, though the save failed of the `@comment`, the comment list in `@car` will still receive an instantiated invalid object return by the comment's `create`, `build`, or `new` method. It is because these three methods will always return instantiated object to the `@car.comments` collection, though it is failed to save it. So we must reload the `@car` object by `@car.reload` to refresh the memory and get correct Comment collection from the database.

---

Previous response:

In crate action, the `create` method `@car.comments.create(..)` will directly create and return an instantiated object without given attributes then try to save it if it passed the validation. If you have not set validations for `Comment` model, then it will directly save it. Try `@car.comments.new(..)` or `@car.comments.build(..)` for collection associations, it will not force to save an instantiated object after the validation passed. Also, check your `Comment` model for setting the validations.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works but what i don't understand is why do i have a row empty in addition when i arrive to my show page. Means if i have 3 comments, i have another empty displayed !! i Use views/cars/show.html.erb

Comment: `@Precode`, for your mention, do you mean you try to create 4 comments, but 1 failed to save and other 3 saved in db? Then you arrive `show` page and got 1 empty comment row and 3 filled comments?

Comment: No i mean when i go to the show page it lists automatically an empty comment plus i think it's because of the comment.new in the method